# How can you check if a phone number was recently moved? (To mitigate SIM swapping)

Tags: phone, simcard, imei

I know never to use phone number as a sole or backup authentication factor. But if a customer forgets their password, and I want to use information they know about their account alongside access to the phone number as a potential avenue to recover their account, is there a way to check if their phone number was recently moved?

For example, is there an API or database I can query for recent historical SIM or IMEI numbers associated with a given phone number?

This would be useful information because it is my understanding that after being hit by a SIM swapping attack, victims usually notice that their phone has stopped working and generally are able to regain access to their phone number within days.

Again, this would not be used as a sole or backup authentication factor, I won't be vulnerable to Twitter-style fully automated SIM-jacking. If the phone number has indeed been associated with the current SIM and IMEI for many months, that would still just be one piece of information among many that would be taken into account in deciding whether to authenticate them.

Comment: [if there were any I'd expect CTIA to mention them](https://www.ctia.org/protecting-against-sim-swap-fraud#what-wireless-providers-are-doing)

Comment: I doubt very much that such a database exists for the public. The opportunity for abuse and tracking people by the public would be huge.

Comment: @schroeder Sure—is there someone I can pay, and go through Know Your Customer-type checks, for access to such an API?